# Return data from service in time

Tags: angularjs

I have a factory, which is returning a ngResource

```
.factory('web'... {
  return $resource(URL, null, {
    create: {method: 'POST'}
  }
}
```

then I have a service which needs to get data from the above factory only if a URL param changed, or if the `variable` where I store the response is empty.

```
var query = Web.get(param);
query.$promise.then(function(res) {
  variable = res;
}
return variable
```

Then I call the above service, to get some data, if `variable` is empty, make a request, else return variable.

The problem is that because of the request I don't get any data, how can I fix this? Also I would like to get the value of `response` not a promise.

UPDATE:

Why I don't need a promise.

At one point I will have all the data that I need, so I don't have to make request on `Web`. So from an array of objects, the user will be able to select one object, and then the `variable` from above will have the value of the selected `object`.

Now my function will return an object instead of a promise, I guess I can check the return type, but I hoped there is another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time your function returns the promise hasn't resolved so you always get `undefined` returned.

You should return the promise to your calling function and let that wait for the promise to resolve or handle any errors.

```
var query = Web.get(param);
return query.$promise;
```

> The problem is that because of the request I don't get any data, how can I fix this? Also I would like to get the value of response not a promise.

Unless I'm very much mistaken, you can't.

**UPDATE based on updated question**

You *still* need a promise to do what you want. Its not too difficult to difficult to wrap it all up.

```
function getData(param)
{
    va deferred = $q.defer();

    if (variable){ 
        // Already got what we need
        deferred.resolve(variable);
    }
    else
    {
        // Lookup the data
        var query = Web.get(param);
        query.$promise.then(function(res) {
            variable = res; // Save for later
            deferred.resolve(variable);
        },
        function(err){
            deffered.reject(err);
        });
    }

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: ` Also I would like to get the value of response not a promise.` This is because at one point I have all the data, and based on a selection, I can send the data to a setVariable method, and then the return will be different.

Comment: @John, not sure what you mean but it sounds like you may need to refactor your code to support the promise. Could you post more of your code, or at least and example that shows exactly what you mean?